# Can a sidecar container of a pod detect the user of the application container and use the same?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-pod, security-context, sidecar

I have defined a sidecar container in a common.tpl file in my helm charts.
This sidecar container is included in numerous pods in which different users are used.

I was wondering if there is a way to define as user in the sidecar container the user of the application container. As a result in each pod the same user will be used for both my application and my sidecar container.

I was imagining something like the below:

```
- name: sidecar_container
  image: sidecar_image:01
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  securityContext:
    runAsUser: {{ some_variable_that_indicates_to_the_application's_container_user }}
```

Is there an option like that?

Comment: Have you read this documentation https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/kubernetes/sidecar ?

Comment: are you looking to know how  to set dynamic values/variables with Kubernetes deployment yaml file?

Comment: Yes, I would like to set the user dynamically to be the same with the application's container user. Although I think that I should follow the Pod level solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the "SecurityContext" at Pod level , which means it will be applied to all containers inside the pod.

[Pod security context](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/website/master/content/en/examples/pods/security/security-context.yaml)

Comment: thanks for your answer, I was aware for that, I am just wondering that instead of modify my helm chart for each pod I can do it at once with a variable in my sidecar container manifest.